# I dont know how to hunt down my problem - React

Tags: reactjs

Im very new to React and im having an issue Im not sure how to troubleshoot. So im setting an array on the context when a http request fails in a custom hook

Here is my hook:

```
const useHttp = (requestObj: any, setData: Function) => 
{
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false); 
    const ctx = useContext(GlobalContext);
        
    const sendRequest = useCallback(() =>
    {
        setIsLoading(true);
        
        fetch(requestObj.url, {
            method: requestObj.method ? requestObj.method: 'GET',
            headers: requestObj.headers ? requestObj.headers : {},
            body: requestObj.body ? JSON.stringify(requestObj.body) : null
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setData(data);                
        })
        .catch(err => 
        {
            setIsLoading(false); 
            ctx.setErrors([
            (prevErrors: string[]) =>
            {
                //prevErrors.push(err.message)
                let newArray = prevErrors.map((error) => {return error});
                newArray.push(err.message);
                return newArray;
            }]
        );
            console.log('There was an error');
        });
    }, []);

    return {
        isLoading: isLoading,
        sendRequest: sendRequest
    }
}
```

Im using .map cos the spread operator for arrays isnt working. Im looking into it but its not important for this.

When there are errors I create a modal and then render it in my jsx. My problem is that for some reason my Modal is rendering twice. The second time it has no props and that blows up my program. I dont know why its rendering again and I dont know how to attack the problem. The stack has nothing with regards to what is causing it (that I can see). If a component is rendering again would the props not be the same as originally used? I have breakpoints in the spot where the modal is called and they arent getting hit again. So can anyone offer some advice for how I go about debugging this?

```
const App: FC = () => {

    const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

    let modal = null

    if(errors.length > 0)
    {
        modal = ( 
            <Modal 
                heading="Warning" 
                content={<div>{errors}</div>}
                buttonList={
                    [
                        {label: "OK", clickHandler: ()=> {}, closesModal: true},
                        {label: "Cancel", clickHandler: ()=> {alert("cancelled")}, closesModal: false}
                    ]
                } 
                isOpen={true}/>
        )
    }

    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={{errors: errors, setErrors: setErrors}}>
            <ProviderV3 theme={defaultTheme}>
                <Toolbar></Toolbar>
                <Grid
                    margin='25px'
                    columns='50% 50%'
                    gap='10px'
                    maxWidth='100vw'>
                    <OwnerSearch />
                    <NewOwnerSearch />
                </Grid>
            </ProviderV3>
            {modal}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    );
};


import { FC, useState } from 'react';

import {
    ButtonGroup, Button, DialogContainer,
    Dialog, Content, Heading, Divider
} from '@adobe/react-spectrum';

type Props = {
    heading: string,
    content : any,
    buttonList: {label: string, clickHandler: Function, closesModal: boolean}[],
    isOpen: boolean
}

const Modal: FC<Props> = ( props ) =>
{
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(props.isOpen);

    let buttons = props.buttonList.map((button, index) =>
    {
        return <Button key={index} variant="cta" onPress={() => close(button.clickHandler, button.closesModal)} autoFocus>
            {button.label}
        </Button>
    });

    const close = (clickHandler: Function | null, closesModal: boolean) =>
    {
        if(clickHandler != null)
        {
            clickHandler()
        }
        if(closesModal)
        {
            setOpen(false)
        }
    }

    return ( 
        <DialogContainer onDismiss={() => close(null, true)} >
            {open &&
                <Dialog>
                    <Heading>{props.heading}</Heading>
                    <Divider />
                    <Content>{props.content}</Content>
                    <ButtonGroup>
                        {buttons}
                    </ButtonGroup>
                </Dialog>
            }
        </DialogContainer>
    );
}

export default Modal;
```

Following Firefighters suggestion I get an error now:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476)
    at useContext (react.development.js:1484)
    at useProvider (module.js:239)
    at $bc3300334f45fd1ec62a173e70ad86$var$Provider (module.js:95)
    at describeNativeComponentFrame (react-dom.development.js:946)
    at describeFunctionComponentFrame (react-dom.development.js:1034)
    at describeFiber (react-dom.development.js:1119)
    at getStackByFiberInDevAndProd (react-dom.development.js:1138)
    at createCapturedValue (react-dom.development.js:20023)
    at throwException (react-dom.development.js:20351)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `open` state inside the App component and remove it from the Modal component:

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);
const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if(errors.length > 0) setIsModalOpen(true);
}, [errors])

<Modal
   ...
   isOpen={isModalOpen}
   setIsOpen={setIsModalOpen}
/>
```

Comment: Nice idea. Its still throwing an error. What im getting in the console is useless. I need to be able to debug it or get back some useful error.

Comment: Is your modal rendering twice after you set the errors after the http request has failed? Or do you mean in general?

Comment: How I had it previously it was after i set errors. Ive hunted down the error thats causing it to fail with your update. it says Im using a hook incorrectly. Ill add it to the original post

Comment: I only use useContext inside the custom hook.

Comment: You can not set state outside of its component. You need to define the http request function inside the component where you are calling it from

Comment: Do not call Hooks inside functions passed to useMemo, useReducer, or useEffect. - yeah thats awkward

Comment: but the whole point of the httpw request function in a custom hook is so I dont have duplicate code every where

Comment: I am not that comfortable with custom hooks. I am sorry, but I think I can't really help you